# How to split one Json to Multiple Json using Angular 2/lodash

Tags: json, angular, lodash

I have a json and i want to split each key value pair to new json object.

**Input:**

```
 tokenData = [{
  "firstname" : "Priya",
  "from": "21-09-2001",
  "to": "22-08-2001",
  "address": "zczxczxczx"
}]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
  tokenItems = [
    {"firstname" : "Priya"},
    {"from": "21-09-2001"},
    {"to": "22-08-2001"},
    {"address": "zczxczxczx"}
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve to that result without `lodash`.

Use `Object.entries`, get the key/values and then use `map` function to create your desired structure of objects.

```js
const tokenData = [{
   "firstname" : "Priya",
   "from": "21-09-2001",
   "to": "22-08-2001",
   "address": "zczxczxczx"
}];

const newTokenData = Object.entries(tokenData[0])
                           .map(([key, val]) => ({ [key]: val }));

console.log(newTokenData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use lodash, Simply you can get this using plan javascript, you need to iterate over the key/value pair for each object like this -

```js
    const tokenData = [{
       "firstname" : "Priya",
       "from": "21-09-2001",
       "to": "22-08-2001",
       "address": "zczxczxczx"
    }];
    
    let newArr = []
    for (let a in tokenData[0]){
     newArr.push({[a]: tokenData[0][a]});
    } 
    console.log(newArr);
```